# how to get array like this?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have one array in php like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => abc
        [id] => 107            
        [CycleNumber] => 1
        [Type] => People
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => john
        [id] => 312         
        [CycleNumber] => 5
        [Type] => People
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [name] => jenny
        [id] => 110        
        [CycleNumber] => 3
        [Type] => People
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [name] => metting room
        [id] => 590 
        [CycleNumber] => 4
        [Type] => Facility
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [name] => projector
        [id] => 470    
        [CycleNumber] => 4
        [Type] => Facility
    )

 )
```

I want to replace the duplicate type with blank. but the first one should have that type name and others should have blank. so the result array should be like this :

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => abc
        [id] => 107            
        [CycleNumber] => 1
        [Type] => People
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => john
        [id] => 312         
        [CycleNumber] => 5
        [Type] => 
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [name] => jenny
        [id] => 110        
        [CycleNumber] => 3
        [Type] => 
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [name] => metting room
        [id] => 590 
        [CycleNumber] => 4
        [Type] => Facility
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [name] => projector
        [id] => 470    
        [CycleNumber] => 4
        [Type] => 
    )

 )
```

I want array in this format only. and i am using PHP zend.

I search for this but most of them showing to remove that element from array. but i don't want to remove it. i want to replace it with blank but want to show the first one.

**Tried Code**

```
$result = array(); 
$result1 = array(); 
$result2 = array(); 
$y = array(); 
$y1 = array(); 
foreach ($data as $entry) {  
    $type= $entry["type"]; 
    if (!isset($y[$type])) {
        $y[$type] = array(); 
        unset($entry["type"]);   
        $result[$type][] = $entry;   
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me how to do that ?

Comment: What have you tried? It is not a hard problem but the answer will depend on what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried this but it will change the array format so i can't use it.  
$result = array();
       $result1 = array();
   $result2 = array();
   $y = array();
   $y1 = array();
   foreach ($data as $entry) {   
    $type= $entry["type"];
    if (!isset($y[$type])) $y[$type] = array();
    unset($entry["type"]);    
   
    $result[$type][] = $entry;  
   }

Comment: Update the question with the code you currently have and include any error messages you may be getting too.

Comment: i think the problem  is ""but it will change the array"" ..not how to convert array

Comment: @Mausami Have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code

```
$i = 0;
$found = 0;
foreach($data as $key=>&$val) {
if($i != 0) {
    if($data[$i]['Type'] == $data[$found]['Type']) {
        $data[$i]['Type'] = "";
    }
    else {
        $found = $i;
    }
} 
$i++;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

## Output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => abc
        [id] => 107
        [CycleNumber] => 1
        [Type] => People
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => john
        [id] => 312
        [CycleNumber] => 5
        [Type] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => jenny
        [id] => 110
        [CycleNumber] => 3
        [Type] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => metting room
        [id] => 590
        [CycleNumber] => 4
        [Type] => Facility
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => projector
        [id] => 470
        [CycleNumber] => 4
        [Type] => 
    )

)
```

## Example